# Set up cucumber to test sinatra app using watir

Tags: ruby, cucumber, sinatra, watir

I'm developing a sinatra app, and I'd like to test it using cucumber and watir. My problem is that I'm not sure how to set up my `env.rb` file to run the sinatra app, all the examples I've found use webrat or capybara or something else that isn't watir. Is there a way to start my sinatra app from cucumber without using webrat or another testing framework that isn't watir, or should I just start my sinatra app manually before running my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

env.rb executes an arbitrary Ruby code as a part of Cucumber setup, so you should be able to start your app or do whatever else you need. Try:

```
require 'YourApp'
YourApp.run!
```

Having said that, it might not be the most logical place to do. An automated build cycle for a web app usually consists of the following steps:

1. Build: compile, copy necessary files, package a binary, etc.
2. Run unit tests
3. Deploy: put the application on a target server
4. Run integration/feature tests

Cucumber and Watir are all about Step 4; therefore, env.rb usually starts a browser. What you are trying to do belongs logically in Step 3, IMHO.